# Check if server running script?

Tags: php

Hello I have a script that does the following:

```
if(isset($_GET['reloadImages']))
{
    echo "<img src='site.com/image.jpg' />";
    exit;
}
```

which happens on index.php?reloadImages

I now have an ajax request to update based on those images:

```
$('#ImageDiv').load('index.php?reloadImages');
```

and that works fine on loading the images, but what I need to know is if you can set a variable like

```
if(SCRIPT_RUNNER == SERVER)
```

so that way it will still retrieve images when the system goes to index.php?reloadImages but not when a user navigates there via url in their web browser

is this possible?

Comment: I assume you mean `echo '<img src="site.com/image.jpg" />';` ?

Comment: PHP is always run by the server, and in both cases it would be doing so upon request by the browser. So, no, not in the way that you're describing. I can imagine a couple of ways of making it harder to open the page directly, but nothing so straightforward, and probably nothing that can't be fooled. What's so bad about the user opening the page directly, anyway?

Comment: *when the system goes to index.php?reloadImages* - What is *the system*?

Comment: @MajidFouladpour, if I understood correctly, he wants a page to be able to be opened only by his AJAX script, not by a user navigating to it directly.

Comment: @ironcito yep exactly what I want to do.

Comment: @ironcito, ah, if so, then: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Answer (score 0):

First find IP address of the machine requesting the link by:

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
   $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']; 
} elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
   $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
} else {
   $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

Now $ip is IP address of the requesting machine.
And let's say your computer IP is 123.456.789.1 (something like that)

So let's assign it to a variable

```
$server_ip  = "123.456.789.1";
```

Now

```
if($ip == $server_ip && isset($_GET['reloadImages'])){
   echo "<img src=\"site.com/image.jpg\" />";
   exit;
}
else{
   echo "Sorry! you cannot see";
}
```

Comment: ahh clever! could I also do this? if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])